# "suspend" hibernate session managed by spring transaction manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is there any way to remove/suspend a current spring managed hibernate session from a thread so a new one can be used, to then place the original session back onto the thread? Both are working on the same datasource.

To describe the problem in more detail. I'm trying to create a plugin for a tool who has it's own spring hibernate transaction management. In this plugin I would like to do some of my own database stuff which is done on our own spring transaction manager. When I currently try to perform the database actions our transaction manager starts complaining about an incompatibly transactionmanager already being used

`org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! HibernateTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single HibernateTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC access.`

A workaround that seems to do the trick is running my own code in a different thread and waiting for it to complete before I continue with the rest of the code.

Is there a better way then that, seems a bit stupid/overkill? Some way to suspend the current hibernate session, then open a new one and afterworths restoring the original session.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't have the current transaction manager injected into your plugin code? Two tx managers sounds like too many cooks in the kitchen. If you have it injected, then you should be able to require a new session before doing your work using the [@transactional annotation's](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) propagation REQUIRES_NEW attribute see the documentation for an example set-up

e.g.

```
@transactional(propogation = Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addXXX(Some class) {
    ...
}
```

But this would use spring's [`PlatformTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html) rather than leaving it up to hibernate to manage the session / transaction.

Comment: problem with doing it that way is that they wrap both the sessionfactory and transactionmanager with their own pieces of code. Another issue with it is that we don't have any way of adding our hbm mappings to their transaction manager

Comment: spring transaction manager wrapped with some of their own coding

Comment: If it is a spring-managed bean and it implements the `PlatformTransactionManager` auto-wiring should do the trick. If it does not implement the interface, you (or they) would have to write some sort of application-specific [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).